# Changing color of cube in three.js

Tags: javascript, colors, three.js

I'm trying to change the color of a cube based on a variable. I created two cubes and I want to change their color depending on the distance between them.

The cubes are created like this:

```
geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry( 50, 50, 50 );
material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff0000, wireframe: true } );
cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( cube );
```

Now I tried something like this:

```
if(distance > 20)
{
cube.material.color = 0xffffff;
}
```

But it does not work. I looked in the examples but couldn't find anything appropriate.

Answer (score 85):

You are not specifying the color value correctly.

```
cube.material.color.setHex( 0xffffff );
```

Comment: You can also use the base-10 integer equivalent as the parameter for setHex, as the two equate in JS.

Answer (score 17):

```
cube.material.color
```

will give you the THREE.Color object:

[Color](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/math/Color)

which has a bunch of methods you can use to set the color.

Comment: Need to have the actual method in the answer in case that link dies.

Comment: Link died, correct answer is color.set(), 'cube.material.color.set( color )'

Answer (score 10):

My suggestion is attach a function to your object and then you can change the color of object during runtime easily.

Based on your code

```
geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry( 50, 50, 50 );
material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff0000, wireframe: true } );
cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

//here is the funcion defined and attached to the  object
cube.setColor = function(color){
     cube.material.color.set(color);
}


cube.setColor(0xFFFFFF)  //change color using hex value or
cube.setColor("blue")    //set material color by using color name

scene.add( cube );
```

Comment: Do not instantiate a new `Color`. Use `cube.material.color.set( color )`.

Answer (score 0):

In the material part you can provide a hexadecimal color value
Like this
`meshMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0xfffff})`
In the following code hexadecimal value (0xffffff) is of colour white