# Change the colors of a cube's faces

Tags: javascript, colors, three.js, mesh, face

I actually found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14181631/changing-color-of-cube-in-three-js) question, but it says `material.color` doesn't exist. I need to know how to change the colors of the various faces of a cube I'm drawing:

```
var newCube = new THREE.Mesh(new three.CubeGeometry(size, size, size), new three.MeshNormalMaterial({ vertexColors: three.FaceColors }));
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**This answer only applies to versions of three.js prior to r.125.**

Here is how you set and change the colors of a cube's faces:

```
var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( size, size, size );
for ( var i = 0; i < geometry.faces.length; i ++ ) {
    geometry.faces[ i ].color.setHex( Math.random() * 0xffffff );
}

var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, vertexColors: true } );
```

If `geometry.faces[i].color` is changed *after the geometry has been rendered*, you  must set `geometry.colorsNeedUpdate = true`.

three.js r.124

Comment: Is there a solution for a newer ThreeJs version?

Answer (score 8):

Here [is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wilt/w67tzfhx/81/) for people who end up here and want to see this code working.

I made a box and tied 3 colors to the faces:

```
// colors
red = new THREE.Color(1, 0, 0);
green = new THREE.Color(0, 1, 0);
blue = new THREE.Color(0, 0, 1);
var colors = [red, green, blue];

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    geometry.faces[4 * i].color = colors[i];
    geometry.faces[4 * i + 1].color = colors[i];
    geometry.faces[4 * i + 2].color = colors[i];
    geometry.faces[4 * i + 3].color = colors[i];
}
```

The face colors are changed in the `animate` loop.

---

Also check [a related question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44828713/paint-cube-faces-as-a-whole-not-the-triangles-that-make-up-the-face-three-js) with [a great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44836160/1697459) demonstrating the use of material indices and groups on `THREE.BufferGeometry` instances.

Answer (score 1):

**For versions greater r.125**

> Each side of your cube consists of two triangles. So the idea is to
> process six vertices per iteration in order to create a single
> (random) color per side.

https://discourse.threejs.org/t/how-to-color-individual-faces-of-a-boxgeometry-tononindexed-object-using-vertices/30099

```
  const piece = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1).toNonIndexed();
  const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    vertexColors: true
  });
  const positionAttribute = piece.getAttribute('position');
  const colors = [];

  const color = new THREE.Color();

  for (let i = 0; i < positionAttribute.count; i += 6) {

    color.setHex(0xffffff * Math.random());

    colors.push(color.r, color.g, color.b);
    colors.push(color.r, color.g, color.b);
    colors.push(color.r, color.g, color.b);

    colors.push(color.r, color.g, color.b);
    colors.push(color.r, color.g, color.b);
    colors.push(color.r, color.g, color.b);
  } // for

  // define the new attribute
  piece.setAttribute('color', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(colors, 3));
  cube = new THREE.Mesh(piece, material);
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/5cm6wvqz/1/)