# What is the most efficient way in three.js to update a face color independently across many meshes that all share the same geometry?

Tags: three.js

In a three.js project (viewable [here](http://www.pixelatedvision.com/2013/07/27/kinetic-light-sculpture-1/)) I have 500 cubes, all of the same size and all statically positioned. On each of these cubes, five of the faces always remain the same color; however, the color of the sixth face can be dynamically updated, and this modification occurs across many of the cubes in a single frame and also occurs across most frames.

I've been able to implement this scene several different ways, but I have not been completely satisfied with the performance of anything I've tried. I know I must not have hit upon the right technique yet or maybe I'm not implementing one quite right. From a performance standpoint, what is the best way to change the color of these cube faces while maintaining independence across each of the cubes?

Here is what I have tried so far:

1. Create 500 individual CubeGeometry and Mesh instances. Change the color of a geometry face as described in the answer here: [Change the colors of a cube's faces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14924187/change-the-colors-of-a-cubes-faces). So far this method has performed the best for me, but 500 identical geometries seems less than ideal, especially because I'm not able to achieve a regular 60fps with a good GPU. Rendering takes about 11-20ms here.
2. Create one CubeGeometry and use it across 500 Mesh instances. Create an array of MeshBasicMaterials to create a MeshFaceMaterial for each Mesh. Five of the MeshBasicMaterial instances are the same, representing the five statically colored sides of each cube. Create a unique MeshBasicMaterial to add to the MeshFaceMaterial for each Mesh. Update the color of this unique material with thisMesh.material.materials[3].uniforms.diffuse.value.copy(newColor). This method renders quite slower than the first method, 90-110ms, which seems surprising to me. Maybe it's because 500 cubes with 6 materials each = 3000 materials to process???

Any advice you can offer would be much appreciated!

Comment: Probably the answer involves using a custom shader material (or extended three.js one). All the cubes would have the same material, and the face color would be figured out by the shader while painting. Also this might be a good use case for BufferGeometry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that three.js performs a WebGL draw for each mesh in your scene, and this is what was really hurting my performance. I looked into yaku's suggestion of using BufferGeometry, which I'm sure would be a great route, but using BufferGeometry appears to be relatively difficult unless you have a good amount of experience with WebGL/OpenGL.

However, I came across an alternative solution that was incredibly effective. I still created individual meshes for each of my 500 cubes, but then I used GeometryUtils.merge() to merge each of those meshes into a generic geometry to represent the entire group of cubes. I then used that group geometry to create a group mesh. An explanation of GeometryUtils.merge() is [here](http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2011/10/05/performance-merging-geometry/).

What's especially nice about this tactic is that you still have access to all the faces that were part of the underlying geometries/meshes that you merge. In my project, this allowed me to still have full control over the face colors that I wanted control over:

```
// For 500 merged cubes, there will be 3000 faces in the geometry.
// This code will get the fourth face (index 3) of any cube.
_mergedCubesMesh.geometry.faces[(cubeIdx * 6) + 3].color
```

Comment: Isn't this GeometryUtils.merge() essentially the same thing as a BufferGeometry?