# threejs coloring a cylinder

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to draw a cylinder with chocolate color 0xd2691e but when I use :

```
var cylinder = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CylinderGeometry(100, 100, 100, 100, 50, false), new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial({ color: 0xd2691e }));
```

It doesn't change the color. And when I use

```
var cylinder = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CylinderGeometry(100, 100, 100, 100, 50, false), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xd2691e }));
```

It does change color, but the color of the top face is the same as the sides, so it ends up like a blob without showing the cylinder 3D shape.

I checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14924187/change-the-colors-of-a-cubes-faces) and it does change the colors of faces randomly, but I would want simply some way to distinguish the colors of the top and the sides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `MeshLambertMaterial`. Also, make sure the scene has a light otherwise it won't show up.

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();

var cylinder = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CylinderGeometry(100, 100, 100, 100, 50, false), new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 0xd2691e }));
scene.add( cylinder );

var light = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff );
light.position.z = 200;
scene.add( light );
```