# How to create multicolored cube in a-frame?

Tags: aframe, webvr

I am using this box primitive entity and I would like to make its various faces show different colors.

```
<a-entity id="box" geometry="primitive: box; width: 1; height: 1; depth: 1" position="2 1 0" rotation="0 30 0" multicolored-cube>
```

Here is the component I am using -

```
<script>
    AFRAME.registerComponent('multicolored-cube', {
        init: function() {
            var mesh = this.el.getObject3D('mesh');
            var geom = mesh.geometry;
            for (var i = 0; i < geom.faces.length; i++) {
                var face = geom.faces[i];
                face.color.setHex(Math.random() * 0xffffff);
            }
            this.el.setObject3D('mesh', mesh);
        }
    });
</script>
```

It still renders the cube with same colored faces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**We need to set the** `mesh.material.vertexColors = THREE.FaceColors;`

```js
AFRAME.registerComponent('multicolored-cube', {
  dependencies: ['geometry'],
  init: function() {
    var mesh = this.el.getObject3D('mesh');
    var geom = mesh.geometry;
    for (var i = 0; i < geom.faces.length; i++) {
      var face = geom.faces[i]; 
      face.color.setRGB(Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random());
    }
    geom.colorsNeedUpdate = true;
    mesh.material.vertexColors = THREE.FaceColors;
  }
});
```

```html
<a-scene>
  <a-entity geometry="primitive: box; buffer: false" 
            multicolored-cube position="0 1 -4" rotation="0 45 0"></a-entity>
</a-scene>
```

[See example in codepen](http://codepen.io/team/mozvr/pen/WxLXGB?editors=1010)

[See three.js question: Change the colors of a cube's faces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14924187/change-the-colors-of-a-cubes-faces)

Comment: you have wrong closing tag in codepen, `</a-box>` should be `</a-entity>`