# Changing colours in three.js, a three js idiosyncrasy?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am attempting to simply change the colour of a cube in three.js to a random colour, I have searched for and referenced [Changing color of cube in three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14181631/changing-color-of-cube-in-three-js), however my code is failing to change the cubes colour even though the console output is correct and setting the colour manually eg`(cube.material.color.setRGB(100,0,0);`) works! What am I doing wrong?

```
var r = 1;
var g = 1;
var b = 1;

var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(1,1,1);
var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial();
var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

scene.add( cube );

var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 'white', 1 );
directionalLight.position.set( 1, 0, 1 );
scene.add( directionalLight );

camera.position.z = 5;

r = Math.round(Math.random() * (255 - 0) + 0);
g = Math.round(Math.random() * (255 - 0) + 0);
b = Math.round(Math.random() * (255 - 0) + 0);


/* issue, the below console output is correct however the colour is not set. Setting the colour values manually works!! */

console.log(r,g,b);
cube.material.color.setRGB(r,g,b);

function render() {

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
    cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
    //cube.position.z += 0.01;



}
render();
```

Answer (score 2):

When setting a `THREE.Color` using the `setRGB( r, g, b )` method, `r`, `g`, and `b` take values between zero and 1.

```
color.setRGB( Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random() );
```

See http://threejs.org/docs/#api/math/Color.

three.js r.85

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please remember to "accept" answers by clicking on the check mark. Thank you.